# Prisma connect to table with custom name, but known schema

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I'm switching from mongodb to prism + postgres, and I need to know how to connect to a table with an arbitrary name, but a known scheme. In mongoose it was like this:
`const TestModel = this.connection.model(‘testModelName’,testModelSchema) test model.create(...)`

now, i create `model TestModel {...}` in schema.prisma, but idk how to create and connect table with custom name e.g. 'testTable123'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In Postgres you connect only to a **database**. Once connected you can reference any schema and/or table to which you have access via a sufficient `Grant`.

Answer (score 0):

After you created testModel. Using prisma client you can connect to the database to read and write data like the following example

```
// First import prisma client
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

// Then use `prisma` in your application to read and write data in your DB
// run inside `async` function
const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
  data: {
    name: 'Alice',
    email: 'alice@prisma.io',
  },
})

const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
```

Also see [Prisma Docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client) to know more